# Auto select the first item from auto complete preview in COC vim?

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

Is there a way to make coc-vim to auto select the first preview suggestion instead of using the arrow key? I'm using vim 8.1.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo im not able to make the options shown to me auto select the first item with :h completeopt . when i type, a lot of autocomplete options are shown but i have to manually select the first one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `"suggest.noselect": false` to your coc-settings.json. You can find the setting in the coc docs.