# In coc.nvim include first entry in autocomplete navigation

Tags: vim, neovim

I have the following snippet in my config for autocomplete navigation:

```
function! CheckBackspace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

inoremap <silent><expr> <Tab>
      \ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) :
      \ CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
```

Now, when the popup menu opens I can press `<CR>` to complete the first entry or `<Tab>` to walk through all other entries. How can I make `<Tab>` start at the first entry (as in accept completion, *not* close the window and on more presses walk through the list)?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65066392/460147

Comment: No, with `"suggest.noselect": false` the behaviour doesn´t change

Comment: Any update on this? No, I don't find "suggest:noselect": false working too.

Answer (score 0):

I set "suggest.noselect" in "true" and it helped me

in vim type: :CocConfig and add

```
"suggest.noselect": true
```